# Скрипт сравнивающий содержимое директорий на bash

Tags: shell, bash, консоль

Как написать скрипт выполняющий сравнение указанных (в качестве параметров) директорий по содержимому на основе информации о размере файлов и дате их изменения? Необходимо вывести для каждого файла имеющегося в обеих директориях примерно такое:

```
$ diff-dir /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2/    
< file1.txt (новее в dir2)
< file2.txt (новее в dir2)
> file3.txt (старее в dir2)
+ subdir1 (отсутствует в dir1)
- subdir2 (отсутствует в dir2)
```

Comment: выглядит как ТЗ, а не вопрос

Comment: поправил

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос старый, но негоже оставлять без ответа.
Как-то так. Уверен, что есть более изящный путь (в bash он всегда найдётся :D), но так - лучше, чем ничего.

```
#!/bin/bash 
ls $1 | while read i
do
if [ -e "$2/$i" ]
then 
    if [ `stat -c %Y $1/$i` -lt `stat -c %Y $2/$i` ] 
    then echo "> $i (старее в $2)"
    else echo "< $i (старее в $1)"
    fi
else
    echo "- $i (отсутствует в $2)"
fi
done

ls $2 | while read i  
do
if [ ! -e "$1/$i" ]
then echo "+ $i (отсутствует в $1)"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

diff -q -r DIR1 DIR2

Это не совсем то, что запрошено, но похоже. В выводе команды нет сведений старее/новее (только Files DIR1/File-x and DIR2/File-x are differ). Можно проанализировать в своем скрипте.

Answer (score 0):

Есть уже готовый fdupes, который умеет сравнивать каталоги и убивать дубликаты. Но вот писать, какие файлы отсутствуют в одном или другом каталоге, он не умеет. Но его или можно использовать в составе shell-скрипта, или просто переписать под свои нужды.

Comment: вы не поняли, мне нужно свой написать!